# Show that the metric d(x, y) = |x−y| / 1+|x−y| is not induced by any norm on $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

Is it because the enlargement property is not satisfied?
Also, is there a way to prove this by contradiction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question essentially contains the answer. Is the distance from $0$ to $2$ twice the distance from $0$ to $1$?